# How do I fix a Win2019 Scheduled Task that fails to launch?

Tags: windows-task-scheduler, windows-server-2019

I have looked at all of the other questions on Stack Overflow related to Task Scheduler and spent hours googling and none of the answers work.

I have created a .cmd file.
I would like to schedule a task to run the .cmd file every day. I want to use a domain service account with limited authority to run the task. I have logged in as the domain service account and confirmed that the account is able to run the .cmd file.

I am able to use a domain admin account to run the task successfully. I have set the task to "Run whether the user is logged on or not" and entered the correct password (it won't let me save if I enter an incorrect password). I have tried granting the domain service account "Allow log on locally", "Log on as a batch job", and "Log on as a service". I have tried adding the domain service account to the local Administrators group.

Regardless, when I use the domain service account to run the scheduled task, I get the following error.

```
Task Scheduler failed to start "xxx" task for user "yyy". Additional Data: Error Value: 2147943726. (Event ID 101)
```

In the event viewer in Applications and Services\Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\Operational, I see the message above and the following error:

```
Task Scheduler failed to log on "xxx" . Failure occurred in "LogonUserExEx" . User Action: Ensure the credentials for the task are correctly specified. Additional Data: Error Value: 2147943726.
```

The messages imply that the credentials aren't specified correctly, but I have copied and pasted the credentials and, like I said before, it won't let me save with incorrect user id and password.

Any other ideas?

Thanks

---- Edit ----

2021-09-28T13:41:11.1856782
    mmm\admin.mp
    Copy Agent Goal Sheet, Agent Performance Sheet, Daily Client Goal, and Daily Client Goal EOM from the file server to the wordpress site
    \Microsoft\Windows\Pull Reports
  
  
    
      2021-09-29T07:00:00
      true
      
        1
      
    
  
  
    
      S-1-5-21-3649111230-1858647485-2366713533-5172
      Password
      LeastPrivilege
    
  
  
    IgnoreNew
    true
    true
    true
    true
    false
    
      true
      false
    
    true
    true
    false
    false
    false
    PT72H
    7
  
  
    
      C:\_Web\_cmd\pullreports.cmd
      C:\_Web\_cmd\

Comment: Is the server a DC or a member server?  Maybe you can export the scheduled task to XML  and link that in the question maybe removing an personal info so we can see the config of the task.

Comment: @HelpingHand, It is just a member server (a web server, to be specific).  I have added the exported task config.  Thanks for looking!

Comment: FYI, error value 2147943726 equates to 0x8007052E, or 052E, or 1326 = `net.exe helpmsg 1326` = `The user name or password is incorrect.`.  Regardless, does the .cmd rely on any environment or profile settings?  If so, then you may need to adjust the "Run whether the user is logged on or not".  What happens if you rename the `.cmd` to a `.bat` file?

Comment: @leeharvey1, thanks for your suggestion, but no joy.  I changed the file to a .bat file.  The .bat file still works when run manually, but still fails to launch when run as a scheduled task.

Answer (score 1):

The service account I was using for the scheduled task was the same service account that I was using for a website.  Apparently when I added the account to the IIS_IUSRS group, the service account was no longer eligible to be used for scheduled tasks.  I created a new service account and was able to successfully schedule the task.